# VSTO-Addin throws InvalidDeploymentException while building the application with second project

Tags: exception, vsto, powerpoint

VSTO-Addin project usually generates a vsto files along with others reference files when build/executed.

But when we include/create a second project in the same solution in visual studio, say WindowsForms/WPF, for using the window from WF/WPF in first project (VSTO).

[My 2 projects in solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw34s.jpg)

So when we build our solution now with two project, with 1st project using form/window from 2nd project, it throws error !!

[Error While installing the VSTO file, after Building the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoZcy.png)

Comment: please give a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Go to 2nd project properties -> Application -> Manifest = Change from [Embed Manifest with default settings] to [Create applciation without a manifest] in drop down.

[Change manifest property for 2nd project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC7b0.png)

[Dropdown select no manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeoZi.png)

[Selected no manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVXIE.png)

Now you should able to build your solution :)

[Installed Successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8c99.png)

**Note:** Even if you have 3rd, 4th projects etc in your solution for the VSTO-Addin project, just don't create manifest for any of them (like mentioned above for project 2).
The first vsto project will create it's manifest by default and you can't edit it, so no issues there.